For duplicate rows, creating a column that shows status based on date
I am hoping for some help with the scenario below in SQL
Current State:

For a particular combination of med_id, casemgr_id, casemgr_clnt_id, the status should be reflected accordingly:
Desired Output:

In the first scenario, for med_id=98410, casemgr_id=12345, casemgr_clnt_id=67891, the date (1strow) is valid, but for the same rows, if the dates fall within 6 months, then the status should be invalid.
In the second scenario, for med_id=91956, casemgr_id=99012, casemgr_clnt_id=87567, the date (1strow) is valid, but for the second row, the status is valid since the date is greater than 6 months.
In summary, for duplicate rows for med_id, casemgr_id and casemgr_clntid, the status for the first row will be valid, but for the subsequent row, it will be valid id the date is > 6 months, otherwise it will be invalid if less than 6 months.
How do I achieve this in SQL? Please assist!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Seems to be similar to this question. There's no way without a kind of loop/recursion.

You can't without window functions, as @Jan Suchanek already showed.
Mine is similar - it also uses LAG(), but it uses some sort of "anchor" using FIRST_VALUE() , to use MONTHS_BETWEEN() upon:
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(id1,med_id,date,casemgr_id,casemgr_cln,status) AS (
          SELECT 123456,98410,DATE '4/19/24',12345,67891,-2
UNION ALL SELECT 789101,98410,DATE '4/24/24',122345,67891,-2
UNION ALL SELECT 234561,98410,DATE '4/25/24',12345,67891,-2
UNION ALL SELECT 567890,98410,DATE '4/26/24',12345,67891,-2
UNION ALL SELECT 456789,91956,DATE '4/20/24',99012,87567,-2
UNION ALL SELECT 998415,91956,DATE '12/20/24',99012,87567,-2
)
-- end of input, real query starts here ...
SELECT
  id1
, med_id
, date
, casemgr_id
, casemgr_cln
, CASE
    WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(
           date
         , FIRST_VALUE(date) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_id, casemgr_cln ORDER BY date)
         )  > 6
      OR MONTHS_BETWEEN(
           date
         , FIRST_VALUE(date) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_id, casemgr_cln ORDER BY date)
         )  = 0
    THEN 'valid'
    ELSE 'invalid'
  END AS status
FROM indata
ORDER BY med_id, casemgr_id, casemgr_cln, date 
;




id1
med_id
date
casemgr_id
casemgr_cln
status




456,789
91,956
2024-04-20
99,012
87,567
valid


998,415
91,956
2024-12-20
99,012
87,567
valid


123,456
98,410
2024-04-19
12,345
67,891
valid


234,561
98,410
2024-04-25
12,345
67,891
invalid


567,890
98,410
2024-04-26
12,345
67,891
invalid


789,101
98,410
2024-04-24
122,345
67,891
valid




It might be someting like
SELECT 
    id1,
    med_id,
    date,
    casemgr_id,
    casemgr_clnt_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_id, casemgr_clnt_id ORDER BY date) = 1 THEN 'valid'
        WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(date, 
                LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_id, casemgr_clnt_id ORDER BY date)) <= 6 THEN 'invalid'
        ELSE 'valid'
    END AS status
FROM your_table
ORDER BY med_id, casemgr_id, casemgr_clnt_id, date;

